# Could I set a part of a tensor untrainable?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gradient, tensor

It's easy to set a tensor untrainable, `trainable=False`. But Could I set only part of a tensor untrainable?

Suppose I have a 2*2 tensor, I only want one element untrainable and the other three elements trainable.

Like this (I want the 1,1 element always to be zero, and the other three elements updated by optimizer)

```
untrainable trainable 
trainable   trainable
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would try to save the desired weights before calling `optimizer.apply_gradients` and change them back to the previous state after calling `optimizer.apply_gradients`. It doesn't prevent backpropagation though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Longer answer: you can mimic that effect by setting part of the gradient to zero after the computation of the gradient so that part of the variable is never updated.

Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(0)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation="sigmoid", input_shape=(2,), name="first"), tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation="sigmoid")])
X = tf.random.normal((1000,2))
y = tf.reduce_sum(X, axis=1)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,y))
```

In that example, the first layer has a weight `W` of the following:

```
>>> model.get_layer("first").trainable_weights[0]
<tf.Variable 'first/kernel:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[ 0.13573623, -0.68269   ],
       [ 0.8938798 ,  0.6792033 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

We then write the custom loop that will only update the first row of that weight `W` :

```
loss = tf.losses.MSE
opt = tf.optimizers.SDG(1.) # high learning rate to see the change
for xx,yy in ds.take(1):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        l = loss(model(xx),yy)
    g = tape.gradient(l,model.get_layer("first").trainable_weights[0])
    gradient_slice = g[:1] # first row
    new_grad = tf.concat([gradient_slice, tf.zeros((1,2), dtype=tf.float32),], axis=0) # replacing the rest with zeros
    opt.apply_gradients(zip([new_grad], [model.get_layer("first").trainable_weights[0]]))
```

And then, after running that loop, we can inspect the wieghts again:

```
model.get_layer("first").trainable_weights[0]
<tf.Variable 'first/kernel:0' shape=(2, 2) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.08515069, -0.51738167],
       [ 0.8938798 ,  0.6792033 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

And only the first row changed.

Comment: Thanks! It's an elegant solution :)